# Asymptotic behavior of Lambert function

Tags: asymptotics, lambert-w

In my calculation, I got 
 $$x^{3/2}e^{-x}=C$$
$$ \frac{3}{2} \log{[x]}-x=\log{C}$$ 
Where $C<<1$, I know that the general solutions to this equation are Lambert Functions, but considering $C$ value I was hoping maybe I can use a simpler, asymptotic behavior of $x$ to make the rest of my calculation easier.
Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know about Lambert function, you know that the solution of $$ x^{3/2}\,e^{-x}=C\implies x=-\frac{3}{2} W\left(-\frac{2 C^{2/3}}{3}\right)$$ For simplicity, let use as notation $a=-\frac{2 C^{2/3}}{3}$.

Now, since $C <<1$, you could use the series expansion built around $a=0$ $$W(a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}a^n =a-a^2+\frac{3}{2}a^3-\frac{8}{3}a^4+\frac{125}{24}a^5+O\left(a^6\right)$$ which is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

There is also Padé approximants which are quite good (better than series) such as $$W(a)\approx \frac{\frac{4 a^2}{3}+a}{\frac{5 a^2}{6}+\frac{7 a}{3}+1}$$ $$W(a)\approx\frac{\frac{451 a^3}{340}+\frac{228 a^2}{85}+a}{\frac{133 a^3}{204}+\frac{1193
   a^2}{340}+\frac{313 a}{85}+1}$$

Comment: @Claude what I got was equal to $x=-\frac{3}{2}(\omega[ Log[\frac{2}{3}C^{2/3}]-\pi i ])$ are these two, both the same thing?

Comment: @ShS. Are looking for complex solutions ? There are three roots to the equation.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici , no just the real solution.I see your point.